# XGBRegressor.predict() returns error after pickle.load()

Tags: pickle, xgboost

I have trained XGBRegressor model using sklearn interface. Relevant code is as follows:

```
def xgb_regressor_wrapper(X_train, y_train):
    xgb_regressor = XGBRegressor(objective='reg:linear', n_estimators=1000, learning_rate=0.01, base_score=0.005)
    xgb_regressor.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train) #, eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)], verbose=True)
    return xgb_regressor

def save_regressor(station, feature, regressor):
    fname = generate_regressor_fname(station, feature)
    pickle.dump(regressor, open(fname, "wb" ))

# regressor_list dict contains wrapper functions
# I currently have XGBRegressor and CatBoostRegressor in the list.
regressor_wrapper = regressor_list.get(name) 

# Create and fit XGBRegressor
regressor = regressor_wrapper(X_train, y_train)

# Save regressor
save_regressor(station_id, feature, best_regressor)
```

Some time later, I use the following code to reload the regressor, and do the predictions:

```
def load_regressor(station, feature):
    fname = generate_regressor_fname(station, feature)
    return pickle.load(open(fname, "rb" ))

# Load the regressor
regressor = load_regressor(station_id, feature)

# Do the prediction
y_predict = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "regressor_stuff.py", line 169, in regressor_check_for_station_feature
    y_predict = regressor.predict(X_test)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\Deep\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 268, in predict
    return self.booster().predict(test_dmatrix,
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

After some debugging, I saw `self.booster` actually stores string 'gbtree'. After training regressor for hundereds of features (which took some days by the way) this was not cool.

Any suggestion for why this could have been happened?

My current workaround is to reconstruct the XGBBooster as follows:

```
# Load the regressor
if isinstance(regressor, XGBRegressor):
    regressor = XGBRegressor()
    r = pickle.load(open(fname, "rb" ))
    print r.get_xgb_params()
    regressor._Booster = r._Booster
    regressor.set_params(**r.get_xgb_params())

# Do the prediction
y_predict = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Thank you

Kursat

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have an xgboost version mismatch in your training and scoring environments. I ran into the same problem and found that I had used xgboost==0.6 for training vs xgboost==0.6a2 for scoring.

Comment: Hi @InfiniteExistence,

Good catch. I have two different environments for XGBoost. I'll check what I can do.

Thanks

K.